# angular-translate: can I use both a custom loader and $translatePartialLoader in my angular app?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I am working on an Angular app that needs internationalization. I have chosen to use angular-translate for this. I cannot store my json translation files locally, because the customer must have the option of updating them, so this means storing them on the server. I also have to map the json response to a TypeScript object, which will then bind to the view as opposed to binding the json object to the view.

To do this, I am using a custom loader which retrieves the json from the server then maps it to an object using angular.extend():

```
'use strict';
angular.module('asecApp')
.factory('translationLoader', function($http, $q) {

    return function(options) {

        console.log(options);

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        let searchViewConfigText = new common.SearchViewConfigText();

        $http.get('server address/locale-' + options.key + '.json').success(function(data) {
            angular.extend(searchViewConfigText, data);
            deferred.resolve(searchViewConfigText);
            console.log(searchViewConfigText);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

This works ok, but does this mean I have to translate my entire app if the language is changed?

I know I can use $translatePartialLoader when the files are stored locally, but can I still use that if I need to retrieve my files from the server and map them to an object or objects?

Comment: Yes, you can use that. partial loader asks for locale json file only. The file path you have to set at the time of configuration.

Comment: options.key will be locale part. So it should work